# Python: Using Imported Tables (.txt files) and Editing For Certain Values to be Omitted

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .txt file with a table as such:

Object Size   Quantity

1      2      3

2      10     3

3      4      1

4      5      2

5      12     1

6      6      2

7      17     4

8      19     2

9      9      3

10     14     2

[Image of Table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWG5f.png)

I have brought this table to Python using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.loadtxt('table1.txt', skiprows=1)
print(X)
```

Now, I want to delete all rows in which the "Size" is smaller than 10. Then, I want to see the 'new' tables with those rows omitted. How can I do that using Python?

Thank you, Q

Comment: You can just use `X[X[:,1] >= 10]` here.

Comment: Did that answered your question ?

Comment: Mark, could you show a full running code using this and maybe elaborate on what operations you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides @Mark Meyer's comment/answer, this is my approach in Python.

```
with open('sample.txt','r') as f:
        c = f.readlines()

c = [ x.strip('\n').split() for x in c[2:]  if x.strip('\n') !='']
# Assign elements to a list [['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '10', '3'] ...

min_number = 10 # ciriteria

c = [c[index] for index, value in enumerate(c) if int(value[1]) > min_number ]
# Keep elements that respect the criteria [['5', '12', '1'] ...
# If you want to keep 10 too, modify list comprehension to >=

# Write output to same file
with open('sample.txt','w') as f:
    for iter, each_line in enumerate(c): # resetting the row number to 1,2, ..
        f.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format( iter+1,each_line[1],each_line[2] ) )
```

Comment: Hi Andreis, I am getting an error on line 9 for "if int(value[1]) > min_number" it says ValueError: invalid literal  for int() with base 10: 'Size'

Comment: I believe it is because the code is reading the first row of the table which lists categories and can't take 'Size' as a value. So maybe we need to delete/skip the first row and add it back later?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be that. Let me get to you (and edit) the answer.

Comment: @QuentindD I have removed the first line by modifying the `c`  from  `[ x.strip('\n').split() for x in c  if x.strip('\n') !='']` to `c[2:]` meaning read from line 2. If you change the 2 to 3 or 4, it will start from that line number (in case you need that for the future).